# Propel 1.6 - Configuration Example?

Tags: php, propel

I'm new to using Propel ORM.  I have generated code and am now trying to integrate the runtime with my PHP project.  I am struggling with initializing the main `Propel` class.  It appears that the usage should be:

```
require_once('propel/runtime/lib/Propel.php');
Propel::configure('/path/to/runtime/config.php');
Propel::initialize();
```

I cannot find any documentation on what the contents on the runtime configuration should be, other than this:

http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.6/RuntimeConfiguration

However, this document shows an XML file, **not** a PHP file.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get error messages or something else which would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually run the generator on it like:

```
$ cd /path/to/project
$ propel-gen convert-conf
```

This will then parse the XML and convert it to the php array. This is all described in the [Runtime Connection Settings section](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.6/BuildTime#RuntimeConnectionSettings) of the docs. You probably need to read the entire Build Time section though if you havent already.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [HOWTO](http://blog.jondh.me.uk/2011/02/some-pointers-on-propel-1-5/) on getting started some while ago - perhaps that might be useful?