# Propel 1.6 - Question About Includes

Tags: php, codeigniter, propel

Any ideas how to avoid adding **20 different `require()` statements** to each one of my CI controllers?

As a follow up to my previous [question about integrating Propel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034908/propel-1-6-configuration-example) with my project, a more involved problem.  I am trying to include a generated class into my application controller.  Here is the code:

```
require_once('PolicytypeQuery.php');

class PolicyType extends CI_Controller {

    function PolicyType() {
        parent::get_instance();
    }


    function index() {
        $data = array();
        $data['policytypes'] = PolicytypeQuery::create()->find();

        $this->load->view('policytype_view',$data);
    }

}
```

The generated class depends on some base class, and I am getting an error that indicates that this base class is not already included somewhere:

```
[Sat Aug 13 16:22:56 2011] [error] [client 97.97.177.2] PHP Fatal error:
Class 'BasePolicytypeQuery' not found in
/var/lib/IPV/util/build/classes/vault/PolicytypeQuery.php on line 16
```

I would **think** that generated code would have the necessary `require()` statements also generated.  However, it doesn't appear so:

```
/**
 * Skeleton subclass for performing query and update operations on the 'policytype' table.
 *
 *
 *
 * You should add additional methods to this class to meet the
 * application requirements.  This class will only be generated as
 * long as it does not already exist in the output directory.
 *
 * @package    propel.generator.vault
 */
class PolicytypeQuery extends BasePolicytypeQuery {

} // PolicytypeQuery
```

Is there a Propel generator option to add `require()` statements into generated code?  Or maybe I'm not autoloading Propel correctly in my project.  To that end, I followed this tutorial on integrating Propel with CodeIgniter:

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Using_Propel_as_Model/

Per step 3, I am including Propel in autoloaded libraries.  Should this be resolving my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should.

PHP has a facility called [autoloading classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). I don't know *propel*, but if it properly uses `__autoload`, you should not need to use any `require` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Propel has its own autoloader, which you should use.

At your initialisation phase in CI, you should initialise Propel thus (see step 2 in the CI link):

```
Propel::init('/path/to/database-conf.php');
```

That file, database-conf.php, is generated by the convert-conf command, together with an autoloader classmap, called classmap-database-conf.php. The former includes the latter - once you have done that your Propel classes will all load automatically.